# Write VS 2010 plugin/addin/extension

Tags: visual-studio-2010, localization, add-in, resx

For my project I was need localization plugin. I dont find it and instead of write own console localiztion utility. I think this will be useful for community.
I want to wrap it into plugin for VS. 
May be already exisists VS addings project templates?
Can anybody help me from what I should start?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and install the [Visual Studio 2010 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff718165). It comes with plenty of sample code.